# Declaring variables and injecting values in yaml from command line or from code

Tags: docker, variables, command-line, docker-compose, yaml

My goal is to have a variable in a yaml which can take values from the command-line dynamically. how to achieve this?

I am trying to replace different secrets in docker-compose.yml for different project. all I want to do is:
 ~/bin/oc create -f docker_baseimages_zookeeper.yaml *secret-name* 
and it should pick the correct secret.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle this issue:

1. Use [environment variables in docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)
2. Use some templating language of your choice to create a template (for example: ERB for Ruby, Jinja for Python)
3. Since I also needed to solve the same problem and didn't like the available solutions, I have developed [kojo](https://github.com/dannyben/kojo) - a command line utility (Ruby gem) to generate configs with templates and variables. Maybe it will help you as well.